# mix.react is not a function? Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-mix

Attempting to use react in a Laravel project.

I have run `npm install`

my webpack.mix.js file is `mix.react('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js');`

and running `npm run dev`

gives me an error

```
/Users/jacobchen/www/fusion2/webpack.mix.js:14
mix.react('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js');
    ^

TypeError: mix.react is not a function
```

webpack.mix.js

```
const { mix } = require('laravel-mix');

mix.react('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js');
```

Anyone had any experience with this?

Best Regards

Jacob

Comment: Is that one line everything you got in `webpack.mix.js`?

Comment: I edited the post with my full mix file

Answer (score 0):

You additionally need to set up laravel-mix in npm script section in `package.json`.

From Laravel's `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
  "dev": "npm run development",
  "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
  "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
  "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
  "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
  "prod": "npm run production",
  "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
},
```

Full example here:
https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/package.json